# Smart electric outlet that can cycle power automatically when power draw falls below certain wattage?

Tags: smart-plugs

I'm looking for a smart outlet (IoT controlled device that allows turning whatever is plugged into it on/off remotely). But, I'm specifically trying to find one that can also be programmed/modified/set so that it will auto cycle power (turn off then back on) if or when the power draw of whatever is plugged into it falls below a certain wattage that I will set (for example 500 Watts)

Please let me know if there's any off-the-shelf IoT device that can do this, and if not, where should I look for info/resources on how to build my own.

Comment: I know of no smart-plug that brings auto-cycling off-the-shelf. A lot can report the power usage however which makes it possible for you to build something like that yourself.

Comment: What is the device you will have plugged in to this socket?

Answer (score 2):

I write this as an answer because it does not fit in a comment.

Generally the safety components are simple, therefore it will take a while to have them in the market safe and "smart". The reason for this is that complex software logic or electronic schematic are difficult to validate as safe components. 
To certificate a device according to the safety norms, this has to  go through a lot of tests and expensive validations. The complexity increases exponentially the risk introducing bugs.

My suggestion, keep safe components simple, use certified devices (without hacking them), and apply your smart implementations just for monitoring them.

There are plenty of electrical component to cut power based on over-consumption/voltage.